# Shortcut key for selecting a word and extending the selection in VS Code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In VS with Resharper, there's the command <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> that will select the whole word at cursor and then, when pressed repeatedly, extend the selection to the brackets, then include them too, then to the next outer brackets etc.

What is the name of the command for that in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The [shrink/expand selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection) commands should be what you are looking for. The command names are `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` (default keybinding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>) and `editor.action.smartSelect.shrink` (default keybinding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart is there anyway for the smartSelect to NOT include the quotes? By default it includes the quotes.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effect of also selecting surrounding spaces.  Seriously not desirable.  A little bit _too_ smart.

Comment: The default keybinding is `ctrl+shift+right`/`ctrl+shift+left` (not `alt`).

Comment: ctrl+shift+right/ctrl+shift+left is not the default keybinding for this. It is the default key binding for smartSelect to grow in a specific direction, left or right. shift + alt + right will grow smart select in both directions simultaneously.

Comment: If the [documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection) is not correct, I would recommend posting it on the [issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) instead of correcting it here. Same goes for the behavior of the commands: If you don't like how the commands work, write your own extension or request an enhancement on the issues page. (I didn't write the code that implements the behavior you don't like, so it's a bit pointless to complain about it here.)

Answer (score 14):

i use alt+s for editor.action.smartSelect.grow.

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mac

- Shirnk: `Cntrl^` + `Shift` + `Left`
- Expand: `Cntrl` + `Shift` + `Right`

Comment: On my Mac, it's option + shift + left/right